# Find a function f(x,y) such that the gradient is

Tags: derivatives

Problem: Find a function $f(x,y)$ such that $ \nabla f = <y,x>$

My work:

$\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial x} = y$

$\dfrac {\partial f}{\partial y} = x$

$f(x,y) =  \displaystyle\int_{ }^{ } \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx +  \int_{ }^{ } \dfrac {\partial f}{\partial y} dy = yx + xy = 2xy$

$\dfrac {\partial (2xy)}{\partial x}  = 2x$

$\dfrac {\partial  (2xy)}{\partial y}  = 2y$

Then shouldn't the function be $xy$?

Comment: no problem ı think.

Comment: ur line $f(x, y) = \int df/dx\,dx + \int df/dy\,dy$ is not correct. Better is to write $f = \int df/dx\,dx = \int df/dy\, dy$.

Answer (score 1):

$$df={(df/dx)_y}dx+{(df/dy)_x}dy=ydx+xdy=d(xy)$$ so $$f=xy$$.

Answer (score 1):

Your method of constructing the function isn't really right. You can proceed as follows:

Since $\partial f / \partial x = y$ then

$$f(x,y) = \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \, dx = xy + h(y).$$

Differentiating this with respect to $y$ gives

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x + h'(y) = x, \text{ therefore } h'(y) = 0 \text{ and } h(y) = C.$$

Hence the family of functions is $f(x,y) = xy +C$.

Comment: Just wondering, what is wrong with the way I did it? It seemed intuitive that I would take the integral of df/dx and df/dy.

Comment: @МикроПингвин You can integrate either way, my choice is irrelevant. The point is that the original function is not the sum of the integrals. If you had a three variable function, you proceed by integrating with respect to one variable, arrive at a result plus some function depending on the two other variables. Differentiate what you get with respect to one of those other two and check. Integrate again, and so on.

Comment: Okay, I found a PDF with an example: http://www.math.wisc.edu/~conrad/f07/potentials.pdf

My textbook didn't have an example.

Comment: @МикроПингвин Mind if I ask which book are you using? Is it russian? I heard Piskunov is pretty good.